# How do I change to colour of a rdlc text field?

Tags: colors, expression, rdlc

I'm using a rdlc report.

I have a text field 'surname' and a boolean field 'sales'.

Depending on the value of the boolean field I want the text to be red or black.

Looking at examples I should be changing the text color.

But the label on the dialog box when I select 'expression' says 'Set expression for:Value' but I think I should be a able to select to set the expression for color.

I have the following expresion but it just displays the text "Black" and "Red" in the text box.

```
=IIF(Fields!sales.Value,"Black","Red")
```

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you are putting expression for value of Textbox. Instead put for Font Color

```
=IIf(fields!sales.Value = "true","Black","Blue")
```

To set expression for fontcolor 
Textbox properties --> color --> Expression.

Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

```
IIF(Fields!MiCampo.value = "Bueno","Green","Red")
```

other solution...

```
Fields!MiCampo.value  TYPE string
VALUE IS = "Orange"
```

In expression...

```
=Fields!MiCampo.value.ToString()
```